# Duplicate WooCommerce Shop to staging (remove orders)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

A client is running an online shop with Wordpress and WooCommerce. Now as their shop grew bigger and the need for more development grew I wanna setup a staging shop for a better and safer workflow. I did a backup of the production shop but I'm wondering how can I remove all order data fast, safe and without **notifying** the customers to get a *production-customer* free staging shop with all the products still available.

I found `define ('WC_REMOVE_ALL_DATA', true);` but that will remove products aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of ways for deleting the WooCommerce orders. You can follow the convenient way. No email notification will be sent to the customer.

**Method 1:** Use this plugin - [WC Delete all orders](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-delete-orders/).

**Method 2:** Go to 'Orders' screen, select (check) all orders and choose `Move to Trash` from 'Bulk Options' dropdown. Click on 'Trash' and click `Empty Trash` button.

**Method 3:** Add this to your theme's 'functions.php', run only once and remove.

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_status = 'trash' WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'");
```

Now all of your orders will be moved to trash and you can delete all by clicking `Empty Trash` button.